# Use senecajs with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, docker-swarm, seneca

I'm currently working on a project where the server side is based on nodejs (express). We use docker-swarm  mainly for load balancing and scalability: In fact, we built a docker image and deployed it under 4 nodes, swarm handles the rest (load balancing).
I've been reading for the past few days about the concept of microservices and that docker can be used to build microservices. I've also read that senecajs can be used to build microservices.

Is it possible to combine both of them? I don't want to touch our current architecture but I'm still interested to use microservices.

Therefore:

- senecajs will be used to separate the functions in express and build
  microservices
- docker-swarm will be used to build containers (mainly for load
  balancing and facilitating the deployment on any server)

Comment: i understand its been quite some time since you last posted this question. Did you end up doing that? i have kinda similar requirement and am exploring options. any inputs will help!! :)